# How to remove space between two div element

Tags: html, css

I got two divs

```
  <div>abc</div>
  <div>def</div>
```

with css as this

```
div{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}

body{
   padding:0px;
   margin:0px;
}
```

how can i remove the gap/space between first and second div

link for the same http://cssdeck.com/labs/i5oysgmt

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Remove the spacing at the code level.

Write like this.

```
<div>abc</div><div>def</div>
```

Comment: downvoter please explain..why -1?

Comment: Probably because it sucks that you have to do this, but you're right. It will fix it.  I upvoted to compensate.

Comment: Each time, after using automatic code indentation in editor, an "Enter" will appear between two elements and create white space again!!! I prefer @ios-newbie 's answer.

Comment: surprisingly, it worked..

Answer (score 5):

```
div{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0px;
  margin-left:-4px;
}
```

Comment: If you are using this dirty trick than make sure you use `-4px`, and I would like to warn you that this is a really dirty solution which will break if the font size varies

Answer (score 2):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/s9wqc/)**

That is because of the white space in `inline-block` elements

html

```
<div>abc</div><div>def</div>
```

[You can read here more](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: Wha about the divs are nav-bars and the code its big?