# How to avoid Div changing positions when another element is added

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem in which whenever I add another element inside, like for example, a P element, my div moves out of position vertically, it's supposed to stick with the top header at all times, but whenever I add another element inside it, it slightly shifts out of position

The background is supposed to be glued to the header on top like this

How it should be[image: How It Should Be]

How it looks[image: How It Looks]

Is there any way to make so the mainbody div ALWAYS sticks to the main header div?

```css
.menucontainer {
         width: 1000px;
         height: 150px;
         margin: auto;
         outline: solid black 1px;
     background-image: url("images/backgrounds/mainheaderbanner.png");
         background-position: -75% 40%;
 }

     .mainbody {
         background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
         position: relative;
         top: -18px;
         margin: auto;
         width: 1002px;
         height: 1345px;
     }
```

```html
<div class="menucontainer">
<a href="index.html">
    <div class="logocontainer">
        <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo"></a></div>
</div>

<div class="mainbody">
</div>
```

Comment: You have messed up tag endings `a` tag needs to be after that `div`. and remove `position: relative and top: -18px` from `mainbody` class, that should work if you do not have anything else that affects your style.

Comment: It didn't work, issue still persists.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sinisa92/owkdcu8s/490/ here check out this is this what you wanted? If yes then something else is affecting element, that you have not posted here...

Comment: What else could possibly be conflicting with the div?

The full HTML + CSS can be seen on my website if necessary (https://junessai.net/)

Comment: Your image example(second picture) and code you posted do not align.

Answer (score 1):

In some Editors each time, after using automatic code indentation, an "Enter" will appear between two elements and create white space again!

To eliminate the space between two divs try to write them in the same line :

in your case :

```
<div class="menucontainer"><a href="index.html"><div class="logocontainer"><img src="images/logo.png" class="logo"></a></div></div><div class="mainbody"></div>
```

test it and tell me if it works!

Comment: You are joking right?

Comment: I'm not making fun I am just amazed someone posted this answer. You made my morning really, had a good laugh. Thank you for that.

Comment: Ok, i am sorry i did not mean to offend you or anything i really thought you are trolling. Sorry once again. I will stop commenting here.

Comment: Each time, after using automatic code indentation in editor, an "Enter" will appear between two elements and create white space again!

Comment: If this is happening to you then my advice is to stop using that editor and use something that is not broken.

Comment: I tested here ; check this out : https://cssdeck.com/labs/i5oysgmt

Maybe his editor has the same problem with that auto white space

Comment: It didn't work
The issue still persists

Comment: Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25132897/how-to-remove-space-between-two-div-element